# GZIP Compression causing web page expiration

Tags: asp.net, gzip

I have implemented GZIP compression on a few of my ASP.NET pages, using a class that inherits from System.Web.UI.Page, and implementing the OnLoad method to do the compression, like so:

```
    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        if (Internet.Browser.IsGZIPSupported())
        {
            base.Response.Filter = new GZipStream(base.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
            base.Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
            base.Response.AppendHeader("Vary", "Content-encoding");
        }
        else if (Internet.Browser.IsDeflateSupported())
        {
            base.Response.Filter = new DeflateStream(base.Response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress, true);
            base.Response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
            base.Response.AppendHeader("Vary", "Content-encoding");
        }
    }
```

The IsGZIPSupported method just determines whether the browser supports GZIP, looking at the Accept-encoding request header, and the browser's user agent (IE5-6 are excluded from GZIP compression). However, with this code, I am getting the web page has expired message in IE, when I postback from the page and try to use the back button. Setting the cache control to private seems to fix the problem:

```
base.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.Private);
```

But I am not sure why, or whether this will cause other problems. I haven't set any caching for any other pages in the site, and the site is running on an intranet with only a dozen concurrent users, so performance isn't a big issue at the moment.

Comment: Why not just turn it on in IIS? http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2004/01/12/57916.aspx

Comment: @ck: It is not always possible to access the IIS console, e.g. you're hosting your site on a web hotel or you are developing a site that another company will host, and you don't really trust that they will know how to set up IIS.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have complete admin access to the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[See this article](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler/Perf/AboutVary.asp) on `Vary` header and WinInet/MSIE

It seems you should be sending `Vary: Accept-Encoding` instead of `Vary: Content-Encoding`, as the response will vary depending on the *request* header.

Comment: Should it matter that I am essentially ignoring the Accept-Encoding request header for IE6?

Comment: Actually, thinking about it, it shouldn't matter because IE6 doesn't have any idea that the pages can be GZIP compressed.

Comment: No, that shouldn't matter. Accept-Encoding means "I *can* deal with those encodings", but you are free to ignore this capability and serve the plain version.